# Pass associative array to PHP API from C#

Tags: c#, php, api, restsharp

I am working in calling `PHP API` from `c#`. But, my problem arise when I have to pass associative array to API. I don't know exact implementation of PHP associative array in C# but I have used dictionary. It didn't works.

I have been using `RestSharp` to call API.

**Code Implemenation:**

```
  var client = new RestClient(BaseUrl);
  var request = new RestRequest(ResourceUrl, Method.POST);
  IDictionary<string,string> dicRequeset = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"request-id", "1234"},
                    {"hardware-id", "CCCCXXX"},
                };
  request.AddParameter("request", dicRequeset);
  var response = client.Execute(request);
  var content = response.Content;
```

**PHP API Implementation(Short):**

```
 * Expected input:
 *   string request[request-id,hardware-id]
 * Return:
 *   code = 0 for success
 *   string activation_code
 */
function activate()
    {
        $license = $this->checkFetchLicense();
        if (!$license instanceof License) return;

        $response = $license->activate((array)$this->_request->getParam('request'));
    }
```

Can someone help me to pass array to PHP API from C#?

Comment: if this api is publicly available, posting which it is might help get some answers.

Comment: Updated the question.Please have a look.

Comment: Can you test the API locally? What does `var_dump($this->_request);` and `var_dump($this->_request->getParam('request'));` say

Comment: Sorry, I can not test API locally. It's third party API.

Comment: shot in the dark, but you could try adding each keyvaluepair as a separate parameter: `request.AddParameter("request-id","1234");`...

Comment: @LorentzVedeler : Sorry, it will not work as api is extracting only "request" parameter.

Comment: Yes, API is expecting `$_request['request'] = array('request-id' => 1234, 'hardware-id' => 'CCCXXX');`. Isn't there a way to test the request array? From the headers when the page is loading? (i.e. firebug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though late post but I've solved this problem by using following approach :

```
        var request = new RestRequest(ResourceUrl, Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("request[request-id]", hardwareId);
        request.AddParameter("request[hardware-id]", hardwareId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe adding the pairs makes differences in conventions in C# and PHP? Have you tried using `Add`?

```
IDictionary<string,string> dicRequeset = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dicRequeset.Add("request-id", "1234"); 
dicRequeset.Add("hardware-id", "CCCCXXX");
```

Or using indexer?

```
dicRequeset["request-id"] = "1234";
dicRequeset["hardware-id"] = "CCCXXX";
```

Or the best I can imagine is JSON as it is designed for the purpose of transmission.

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = serializer.Serialize(new {request-id = "1234", hardware-id = "CCCXXX"});
```

The problem in the third variant despite I marked it as the best, might be that the PHP API may not decode the JSON string, because it might not be designed that way. But in general purpose JSON is meant to solve that kind of problems.

Comment: +1. But I have tried all ways you specified but seems no luck.

Comment: Oh, sorry I couldn't help. Right now I'm out of ideas. I will do a research, but I guess you are doing to. If you find you answer you can post it. I will do the same if I succeed.

Answer (score 0):

if I guess right, the `AddParameter` method of `RestSharp` doesn't automatically serialize an object to json thus insteadly just calls the object's `toString` method. 
So try to get a JSON.net library and make the json encoding manually,

```
IDictionary<string,string> dicRequeset = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"request-id", "1234"},
                    {"hardware-id", "CCCCXXX"},
                };
var jsonstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dicRequeset);
request.AddParameter("request", jsonstr);
```

this should work.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. There is no any json decoding in api method.

Comment: JSON.net has been removed from dependency of RestSharp, it needs to be added manually as a library.

Comment: @hago what will be the structure of request after this?

Comment: the http body would be like request=%5B%7B%22request-id%22%3A+%221234%22%2C+%22hardware-id%22%3A+%22CCCCXXX%22%7D%5D

Comment: this would not work as PHP is expecting `$array['request']['request_id'] = "smth";`

Comment: I don't know what framework you use in php, usually php can read the json string "%5B%7B%22request-id%22%3A+%221234%22%2C+%22hardware-id%22%3A+%22CCCCXXX%‌​22%7D%5D" from $_POST with key "request" and use json_decode() to convert it to an array.